# Cover different types of values in Vector

Tags: vector, rust, types, error-handling, panic

I want to handle different types of value I get via `[]` or `get()` methods of Vec.
But somehow it throws me an error.
I meant I should be able to cover all the occurrences(Types) in the Vec.
In the example, `d_vec[0]` is of Type `Spreadsheet::Text(String)`. It always shows me that I need `String` as expected value, but that can be, that I won't know the exact type (out of these 3 `Spreadsheet`) of the value I'm trying to get via `[]` or `get()`.
Code:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Spreadsheet {
    Text(String),
    Float(f32),
    Int(i32),
}

let mut d_vec: Vec<Spreadsheet> = Vec::new();
d_vec.push(Spreadsheet::Text(String::from("SOME TEXT")));
d_vec.push(Spreadsheet::Float(5.0f32));
d_vec.push(Spreadsheet::Int(10i32));

let b: Spreadsheet = d_vec[0];
    // Catch values of different types
    match b {
        Spreadsheet::Text(v) => v,
        Spreadsheet::Float(v) => v,
        Spreadsheet::Int(v) => v, 
    }
```

It suggests me to use conversion via `.to_string()`, but right after the conversion it throws an error about expected `()` instead of `String`

[Before using to_string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK1Od.png)

[After using to_string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFuhL.png)

Will appreciate any help, because It's driving me crazy :(

Comment: `match` arms must resolve to the same type, so `.to_string()` works because it forces them all to return `String`, the next error you get seems to be that you're at the end of a function and is thus attempting to return a `String` when the function signature is `()`, add a semicolon after the match like the error message says, or explain more what your match is supposed to do

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Ah, worked with python and forgot that Rust consume lack of semicolon at the end of the function as the exit point. Thanks, mate! everything like you have written, `ref` and `to_string()` fixed it!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.